# Integrating Ember.js with Spring Framework

Tags: java, json, spring, ember.js

Integrating Ember.js with Spring Framework.

I am trying to save firstname and lastname of customer but I am getting `null` values. I am using ember on Client side and server side Java application with spring framework.

> WARNING: The server returned an empty string for POST, which cannot be parsed into a valid JSON. Return either null or {}.

Server code (Java Application):

```
@PostMapping(path="/createCustomer")
public void createCustomer(@RequestBody EmberCustom createCustomer) {
  System.out.println("Firstname:"+ createCustomer.getFirstname() + ", Lastname: " + createCustomer.getLastname());
    }
```

Output :

> Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
>   Firstname:null, Lastname: null

Comment: How you are trying to save it?

Comment: Using ember data (customerdata.js )                                                                   actions: {
  create: function(){
   var model=get(this,'model');
   model.save();
  }

Comment: but you are not returning anything. You should change your method a declare `public ResponseEntity<EmberCustom> createCustomer...` for example ... the `System.out.prinlnt` print only in the console of the server ...

Comment: well, apparently the problem is inside your method `getFirstname` and `getLastname` you should post the code.

Comment: public  ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(@RequestBody EmberCustomer createcustomer) {
  String ec = createcustomer.getFirstname()+" "+createcustomer.getLastname();
   System.out.println("Firstname & Lastname:"+ ec  );
  return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(ec);}

Comment: @winter public class EmberCustomer {

 private long id;
 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;
 private String signature;

 
 public String getFirstname() {
  return firstname;
 }

 public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
 }

 public String getLastname() {
  return lastname;
 }

 public void setLastname(String lastname) {
  this.lastname = lastname;
 }

Comment: it's just a POJO, how are you calling your method from the client side?

Comment: @winter Thanks I have checked again changed getFirstname() to getfirstName() and It was my mistake in declaring the method .Now with ResponseEntitiy I can get JSON response

Comment: @winter It is working public ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(@RequestBody EmberCustomer createcustomer)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `public void` method you should return `ResponseEntity<String>` for example.
So, you'll have a method like this:

```
@PostMapping(path="/createCustomer")
public ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(@RequestBody EmberCustom createCustomer) {
    String var = "Firstname:"+ createCustomer.getFirstname() + 
                 ", Lastname: " + createCustomer.getLastname();
    System.out.println(var);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(var, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```